# Index autoincrement for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity

I created a new table in SQL Server 2008 R2, and i would like that the index is on autoincrement.
How to do that? There is no identity data type; i selected int

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In SQL Server, it's not a separate datatype ("autoincrement") - but you **can** define an `INT` column to be an `IDENTITY`.

How are you creating your table - visual designer or T-SQL script??

In T-SQL, you would use:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ......
```

and in the visual table designer, you need to check:

[image]

It's an option for a column of type INT - you can define the seed (starting value) and the increment - typically both are set to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using MS SQL Management Studio - visual designer

Answer (score 2):

If your table definition is like this,

```
....,
@id int,
....
```

change it to,

```
....
@id int identity(1,1),
....
```

This will create an identity column which starts id with 1 and keeps increasing it by one(i.e. step) as each record in the table is inserted.

Comment: Where does @id come into it please?