# Increment number by 1 insert into database using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

If possible I would like to increment a number on the application side and save to the database using c# and Linq.

So for example I have a table like so:

```
|id|text|version|
-----------------
 1  hello   1
 2  hello   1
```

When inserting a new record into this table I want to get the current version number and increment by 1 then insert a new row

```
|id|text|version|
-----------------
 1  hello   1
 2  hello   1
 1  hello   2
```

I can do a standard insert using linq but obviously stuck with what to do with the version

```
DataContext db = new DataContext

using (db)
{
    table t = new table
      {
         text = TextBox1.Text
         version = ??
      };

db.table.InsertOnSubmit(t);
db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Can I somehow select the row and get the current version number and then just increment by 1? Or should I just re-think my approach?

Thanks

Comment: When I've done this I've either used a stored procedure to do the insert or otherwise controlled the value of the `version` column in the database itself.

Comment: _"should I just re-think my approach?"_ Yes, you should let the [database increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4228090/284240) is a sql-server only link that shows how to set `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Usually, systems built with asp.net will be accessed by multiple users, in parallel. Is there something inherent in your design that means that there's no possibility that two users will attempt this same operation at the same time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter can't use the database increment because I insert a new row and it could be of any id. Damien, I was just going to use optimistic concurrency that is included in linq. I'll definitely re-think, thanks for the comments.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , According to the above given data Version is not a unique column so you can not add the auto increment property to that column.

Comment: @KrishnaThota: Yes, I have seen it already. But he should do that in the database anyway and avoid race conditions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Got your Point, If he does not use the auto increment, You say, it will be a problem. I think the problem can be solved by using Locks.//Obtain lock for Version
  //Insert Data
//release lock for Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the liberty to change the database structure so I just used IDENTITY col.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'll need to wrap this logic inside a transaction; it will lock the table and you'll avoid concurency issues.
After that, you can just select the maximum value of version and increment it by one.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                      new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable}))
{
    using(var dataContext = new DataContext())
    {
        var version = dataContext.Table.Where(item => item.Text == textBox1.Text)
                                       .Max(item => item.Version);
        var t = new Table
        {
            Text = textBox1.Text,
            Version = version + 1
        };
        dataContext.Table.InsertOnSubmit(t);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I especially like the use of the TransactionScope, although I am going to try something different.

Comment: Bearing in mind that using a transaction then doing significant work inside the transaction can impact scalability because it will force serialization...

Answer (score 0):

**Using SQL Stored Procedure**

I can suggest you a method to do this in sql server. Use SQL Stored Procedure. If you use link there will be a disadvantage, the control will be running so many no of times.

Try this if you want to use Stored Procedure

```
DECLARE @sno INT
IF((SELECT MAX(version) FROM Tbl) IS NULL)
SET @sno=0;
ELSE SET @sno=(SELECT MAX(version) FROM Tbl)

INSERT INTO Tbl (Id,Text,version)
VALUES (@id, @text, @sno)
```

In the above code, @sno is a available and it is set to 0 in the start and if any previous version nos doesn't exist, then version is set as 0 . If any version exist, then the version is incremented by one and then inserted.

**Using LINQ**

By using LINQ,

```
var maxVer = dc.Logs.Max(s => s.Version);
```

This givesthe max version no. and using this you can insert into DB in your way.

Comment: This is still subject to race conditions, unless you're inside a transaction with high isolation. Two connections could both detect no rows in `Tbl`, then both attempt to insert the `0` row (and similarly, both detect the same current max and attempt to insert max+1)

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote in harder way. I didn't get your Idea

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to try something different though.

Comment: Okay @luke2012 . After you succeeded doing it please post it here and we will be knowing and will learn if it is unknown to us.