# How to get next value of autoincrement column MVVM

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvm, auto-increment

Here is the code first and i'll describe what I'm trying to find out below it:

**ViewModel**

```
private ServiceReference1.tblUser user;
    public ServiceReference1.tblUser User    
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("User");
        }
    }

 public ICommand _addUser;
    public ICommand addUser 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addUser == null)
            {
                _addUser = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {                            
                        Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
                        wcf.AddUser(User);
                        Users.Add(User);
                        wcf.Close();

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }

            return _addUser;
        }
    }
```

**WCF**

```
  bool IService1.AddUser(tblUser user) 
    {

        try
        {        
            context = new HotelBaseEntities();               


            context.AddTotblUsers(user);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.Message.ToString();

            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Description:**
On WCF service I have ADO.Net EntityDataModel (EF 4), it contains table "tblUsers". "tblUsers" have primary key column named "UserID" and it's autoincrement. The method on WCF is used for adding new record to "tblUsers". I do this by sending property "User" to WCF. This filed ("UserID") is 0. Is it possible to somehow get the next value of autoincrement column immediately when adding new record? I mean can this 0 value be somehow changed with the next vaule of autoincrement column? My database is created in SQL Server management studio 2005.

**EDIT**

I have form for adding new user to database. It has textboxes that are bound to property User. This textboxes are used for inserting Name, Username and Password for new user. I have this columns in "tblUsers". So when i fill textboxes with this values, and click on the button, the property User get those records. But UserID is 0 becouse i dont have textbox for inserting that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct: You should turn it on in your database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228073/index-autoincrement-for-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: No I allready turned it on. The problem is when I adding new record UserID is 0 becouse it's not in database yet. So it get value after being added to database. But i want to manage that it get the value before being added.