# Best practice to stop duplication of a ++ incremented number being populated in a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I'll try to word this as best I can.

I'm coding a website using C# MVC4 with a MS SQL database. Whenever a user submits an application via the website I do a look-up on the table, find the highest numbered session code (7 digit, number) add 1 to this number and populate it in the database along with the user details.

We are on the verge of starting a huge add campaign and there will be a massive influx of users. I am worried that if two users submit their applications at the same time that the same session code will be generated for both. What are some practices to stop this? I'm thinking make the field unique in the DB and have a loop surrounding my session code generation and population to try again should it fail.

Is there a better practice than this (other than creating a composite primary key)?

Comment: Can you show your Database table structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the number `identity` starting from any number you like. Then the DB will add 1 to the highest number by itself.

See [the MSSQL doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Juergen, thanks for the answer (although I'm using MS SQL, but I'm pretty sure this is just as easy to do in MSSMS). My question now is, if say 3 people all apply at the same time, for the first application to get through will cause the current number to auto increment, does the database then essentially hold this number somewhere so that the next call for an auto increment that comes through will look up the held number rather than the last number in the database?

Comment: A DB handles that by itself. You can have thousands of requests per seconds and the DB will always generate only unique numbers. The request that comes first will be served first.

Answer (score 1):

You might set the number to the identifier and let it autoincrement [Index autoincrement for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228073/index-autoincrement-for-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2)

Otherwise if it is possible to change the datatype - create Guids (uniqueidentifier in the database). Then your quite safe against collisions

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks. This answer is similar to Juergens above, if you see the question I have asked him off the back of it you will see my next concern. A Guid is not feasible as the customer is given the application code as a reference number to use for various legal processes and identification processes on the website.

Comment: Yeah saw that I was a little bit too late (started writing when no answer was here). But as juergen already told you, the database will handle this for you, so your safe there. The Guid solution is when you want to generate the IDs in the code (like you currently do). Although I can't see your reasoning why it shouldn't be feasible? It is an identifier and its unique and it can be provided. Is it too long? Should it be a number?

Comment: It's more to do with the fact we are giving these out to customers to quote to our agents and visa versa and they need to be hand written in a few places (as per the way our business works) so it needs to be a relatively small number that is easily quoted etc.

Comment: Ok when the stuff is written by hand... Oh modern times :-) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server Management Studio set the column properties to

Identity Specification Yes
(IS Identity) Yes
Identity Increment 1
Identity Seed [Your last Number]

This will set that column to auto increment, you then no longer need to set this column when submitting data to the DB