# MVC Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using code first and the automatically generated Views. Withing the model I have a Column set to unique.

However when it reaches db.SaveChanges(); I get an error due to there being a duplicate in the database.

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Columns")] Tv tv)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tv.Add(tv);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tv);
    }
```

**How can I create an error message and send the user back to the previous page displaying that error? I have tried a try catch but it  didn't work**

Comment: You can use the return value: "The number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state when SaveChanges was called." Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it an exception? can u post the exact msg?

Comment: @RotemVaron - yes this is the exception `Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Tv' with unique index 'IX_TvTitle'. The duplicate key value is (Camping).
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: the error originated from the DB, not your code. Can you try this on the TV table? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228073/index-autoincrement-for-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2 AND https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITneqe2OCwY

Comment: Sorry what is it you would like me to do exactly? I already have a unique column and an identity column

Comment: Did you set the Identity seed a well?

Comment: I used `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` inside my model to set it

Comment: What is the .NET / MVC version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of the save method. I would also add a try/catch.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Columns")] Tv tv)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           try
           {
              db.Tv.Add(tv);
              int num = db.SaveChanges();
              if (num == 0)
              {
                 //prompt user
              }
              return RedirectToAction("Index");
           catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
           {
                 // handle the exception
           }
        }
        return View(tv);
    }
```

Comment: The try catch causes the same Exception to be happening with the `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @niko619, it seems that the Identity Increment (and seed) were not set on the TV table. Can you try and report back?